# How to use a UI router in order to resolve a promise before it is passed to the controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-promise

I have an issue with Angular promises and would need help on how to best use them.

I have a `domainService` that retrieves data from the server-side as follows:

```
parentsNeeds: function () {
    return $http.get('/api/utils/parents-needs', {
        cache: true
    });
},
```

I have a `constantsService` that uses the `domainService` in order to convert an array to an object as follows:

```
.factory('constantsService', ['domainService', '$q', function (domainService, $q) {

        var convertToObject = function (param) {
            var parentsNeeds = {};
            for (var i = 0; i < param.data.length; i++) {
                parentsNeeds[param.data[i]] = i;
            }
            return parentsNeeds;
        };
        return {
            PARENTS_NEEDS: domainService.parentsNeeds().then(convertToObject)
        };
    }]);
```

In UI router configuration, I have the following resolve:

```
resolve: {
    constants: ['constantsService', function (constantsService) {
        return {PARENTS_NEEDS: constantsService.PARENTS_NEEDS};
    }]
}
```

In my controller, I inject the `constants` resolve and use it as follows:

```
constants.PARENTS_NEEDS.then(function(param){
   var PARENTS_NEEDS = param;
});
```

The trouble is that the `PARENTS_NEEDS` var available in my controller and given it is obtained from a promise, and I have to use pass in a callback to the then method, the `PARENTS_NEEDS` var is only available in the callback scope.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: In ui-router resolve you actually can simply return a promise. Ui-router will not load the view until the promise is resolved. I guess you could try to directly return "constantsService.PARENTS_NEEDS"

Comment: @Okazari, yes it does work fine. Thanks. However, how could I encapsulate several constants into a constant object in order to avoid having to inject a unreasonable number of constants into my controller (I have quite a few...)?

Comment: If these are `constants` can't you have the service return them all as a single object in one promise?

Comment: Hi @charlietfl, how so? I am not sure how to do that..

Comment: Do they all require api calls? If so can use `$q.all`

Comment: Works a charm. Thanks to all. Bear with me whilst I post a reply based on your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Charlietfl & Okazari's suggestions and comments, I came up with the following:

My redesigned service:

```
.factory('constantsService', ['domainService', '$q', function (domainService, $q) {

    var convertToObject = function (param) {
        var object = {};
        for (var i = 0; i < param.data.length; i++) {
            object[param.data[i]] = i;
        }
        return object;
    };

    var PARENTS_NEEDS = domainService.parentsNeeds().then(convertToObject);
    var CHILDCARE_WORKER_TYPES = domainService.childcareWorkerTypes().then(convertToObject);
    //and so on and so forth...


    return {
        constants: $q.all({PARENTS_NEEDS: PARENTS_NEEDS, CHILDCARE_WORKER_TYPES: CHILDCARE_WORKER_TYPES})
    };
}]);
```

In my UI router:

```
constants: ['constantsService', function (constantsService) {
    return constantsService.constants;
}]
```

I then get a nice `constants` object (resolved promise) in my controller. The object contains both constants:

```
Object {PARENTS_NEEDS: Object, CHILDCARE_WORKER_TYPES: Object}CHILDCARE_WORKER_TYPES: ObjectASSISTANTE_MATERNELLE: 1AUXILIAIRE_PARENTALE: 0AU_PAIR: 3BABY_SITTER: 2__proto__: ObjectPARENTS_NEEDS: ObjectPARENTS_TO_CHILDCARE_WORKER: 0PARENTS_TO_PARENTS: 1__proto__: Object__proto__: Object
```

Comment: that's not really what I had in mind...can make it cleaner by passing the actual `$http` promises to `$q.all` . What you are passing aren't promises they are objects containing promises. You would use `.then` to return the constants object